# Windows 7 64-bit programfiles environment variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, environment-variables

Does anyone know if windows 7 will somehow defer back to the "ProgramFiles(X86)" environmental variable when the "ProgramFiles" variable is used?

We have a situation where a developer is using visual studio and the proj file references assemblies using "$(ProgramFiles)".  The machine is 64-bit and the "ProgramFiles" variable points to "C:\Program Files", however the assemblies are in "C:\Program Files (X86)" yet the project builds.  It does not build if the literal "C:\Program Files" path is used.  The compiler says it cannot find the assemblies

Comment: Hans answer is correct and you can find more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Windows automatically maps folder and file access to `c:\program files` for 32-bit programs to `c:\program files (x86)`.  Visual Studio as well as MSBuild are 32-bit programs.  Same is true for c:\windows\system32 vs c:\windows\syswow64.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I thought.

Comment: I don't think this is true except for the use of the environment variable %ProgramFiles% which does automatically provide the correct path depending on the bitness of the process.  The reason the OP's situation works is because VS is 32-bit and `$(ProgramFiles)` refers to the environment variable %ProgramFiles% which will be `C:\Program Files (x86)` for a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS.  If I fire up a 64-bit exe in `C:\Program Files\Acme\foo64.exe` from a 32-bit process the OS just switch the path on me to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Acme\foo64.exe`.